# The effect black holes have on light

Tags: visible-light, black-holes, photons, spacetime, energy-conservation

We all know that light loses its energy when it is moving through expanding space and time. And sense a black hole can be summed up to a super compressed space time, shouldn't that mean that a photon gains energy when it enters a black hole because it is experiencing the opposite effect of the expansion of spacetime

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(physics)

Comment: As is usual in these kinds of questions - according to who?

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of an observer far from a mass:

Light gains energy (increasing in frequency) when it goes from farther away from a mass to closer to a mass. Energy is conserved: the increase in the energy per photon is equal to the decrease in gravitational potential energy caused by bringing the mass-energy of the photon closer to the mass-energy of the mass.

If the light subsequently gets farther away from the mass, the same relation holds, so the frequency goes back down.

These are *gravitational blueshift* and *gravitational redshift* respectively.

A black hole is just a special case; all masses exhibit this phenomenon.

---

So far as I know, it is unknown whether gravitational redshift and the cosmological redshift caused by the expansion of spacetime are one in the same. As a non-expert, I find the explanation compelling, since the universe expanding moves mass-energy (including photons) farther apart, and this must do work on the gravitational field.

Answer (score -1):

Basically yes it does lose energy and it can not get it back. For your second qwestion well, we don’t know what happens in a black hole but we have general ideas of what happens in there and basically it’s just contrubiting energy into the black hole BUT a black hole could just be a incredibly different thing like a worm hole so you would have to be more specific with your qwestion

Comment: im talking about what happens to a single photon when it enter a black hole does it get compressed or does it under go something else entirely